# Deploying an updated DLL to multiple ClickOnce manifests

Tags: vb.net, dll, clickonce

I'm somewhat new to deploying ClickOnce manifests, first off. I know the basics of how to publish to an app server, which then lets every use the newest version (after setting to check for updates before running the application).

We have multiple VB.Net applications stored on our app server, that cover a lot of different areas of the company. However, all of them connect to our Oracle database in the same way. So, my thought was to create a DLL containing commonly used functions, such as decrypting and reading our connection string, among some very common SQL functions/statements that we use a lot. Then, instead of copying and pasting the same code into each .Net program, it would be stored in one place. Of course, the major benefit to this would be that if we change the method we use to connect to the database, or need functions modified/added, we don't need to open each program, paste it in, and .republish

So, I did a test where I took a program that I wrote, added the DLL to it and tested it out. It works great. Then I took the source code of the DLL, made a change to show a message box at the beginning of a function, rebuilt the DLL, and dropped it in place of the copy that was being referenced in the test program. When I run the program, it's still using the original DLL without the message box code.

My question is, how could I accomplish what I would like to do without having to republish each and every .Net program that uses this DLL whenever a change is made to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1

Instead of publishing your dll library via click once, Put a web service wrapper around your dll class library. Each Click once application will have a reference to the web service which will run on a web server.

Your code in the dll will then be running on the web server. Any changes to the dll code will only need to be updated on the web server. You'll have to be careful to keep the interface changes to a minimum.

Option 2

push out the dll as an separate MSI install. Reference the dll in your click once apps code and make sure you don't deploy the dll with the click once install. Changes to the dll will be pushed out separately.

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely helpful. I found another solution as well, by loading the DLL at run time and using an interface class to use in the code while writing it. Not sure which method I will go with yet, but this definitely helped a lot!